# Getting mongoose not defined error in model file

Tags: node.js, mongodb

`mongoose` module already installed also included in `index.js`

In `index.js`

```
mongoose = require('mongoose').connect(config.dbURL),
...
require('./routes/routes.js')(express, app);
```

In `routes.js`

```
var Category = require('../models/category');
...
```

Within model folder `category.js`

```
var categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        category_name:String,
        alias:String,
        added_on:String
    });
```

but error occurred while using in model file.

Folder structure:

```
server
-> index.js
-> routes/routes.js
-> models/category.js
```

[image]

Comment: Did you require Mongoose in category.js? `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`?

Comment: Mongoose will need to be `require`d in each file explicitly. However the code for connection needs to be specified in only one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this line in category.js pages top :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```